# Вылетает приложение при использовании Preferences

Tags: java, android

Учусь работать с Preference, и при его использовании вылетает приложение

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    saveText();
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    H.setLevel(1);
    H.setLevelTime(33000);
    scoreText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.scoreText);
    StartGameBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.StartGameBtn);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);
    loadText();
}
void loadText() {
    H.sPref = this.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    savedText = H.sPref.getString(H.SAVED_TEXT, "");
    scoreText.setText(savedText);
}

public void saveText() {
    H.sPref = this.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor ed = H.sPref.edit();
    ed.putInt(H.SAVED_TEXT, 0);
    ed.commit();
}
```

Comment: Верно ли написан этот код?

Comment: где вылетает то именно? где описание ошибки?

Comment: что такое `H` ?

Comment: Почему saveText кладет интовое значение? ed.putInt(H.SAVED_TEXT, 0);

Comment: 'public static SharedPreferences sPref;
    public static String SAVED_TEXT = "saved_text";' 
это в H классе

Comment: этот метод просит интовое значение

Comment: Вы вызываете `saveText()` до `super.onCreate`, возможно в этом проблема.

Comment: вызвал после, не помогло

Comment: Отредактируйте вопрос, добавьте в него объявление класса и его полей (чтобы мы не гадали, что такое `H`), текст исключения и трассу стека. Можете так же указать строку (комментарием в коде), на которую указывает исключение.

Comment: Добавил ответ к вопросу. Но, все равно подредактируйте ваш код на 99%. И saveText() в первую очередь. putString у преференсов есть такой метод

Comment: Помогло, спасибо

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu); 
scoreText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.scoreText);
tartGameBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.StartGameBtn);
```

Вот в таком порядке. Вы дергаете объекты по айдишникам, пока разметка еще не легла в Activity